# Looking for a formal word has the same meaning of "well done"

Tags: word-choice, word-request, formal-language

I once heard a friend say a word to a friend who had just had a new born baby. As I looked it up in the dictionary, I found its meaning equals "***well done, nice job or praise someone for their nicely done job***", but it's a formal word, like **Congratulations**, or **my Condolences**.

Unfortunately, now I've forgotten the word, I hope that someone here might help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: Can it be *"Greetings, my friend..."* ?

Comment: @GATA no it's not, kind of a long one

Comment: How do we read your friend's mind? And there might be 100s of words to refer to the event -formally and informally. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Felicitations* is a synonym for congratulations.
It fits your description.

Although, as others have commented, there could be a number of possibilities.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that this is not a very commonly-used word. You might even get some funny looks if you use it in every day conversation.